# I am trying to create an interactive PDF that uses formulas from an Excel tax calculator that we have created

Tags: adobe-indesign, microsoft-excel

Our graphic designer sent me a half completed project. He can not seem to transfer the actual formulas from the Excel spreadsheet into the fields of the PDF to calculate.

Comment: Maybe I am reading this wrong but are you trying to do a data marge by taking the values from Excel and inputing them into InDesign or are you doing user input into an Interactive PDF. Also are you doing basic formulas (Addition / Subtraction / Multiplication / Division)?

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to the site. We don't have much to go on from what you've posted... for starters there's  no actual question! Please [edit] your question to include all relevant details including what you've attempted so far that hasn't solved your problem, tutorials you may have come across, or even search terms that you've used when trying to find the answer on the web.

Comment: A pdf is NOT a spreadsheet. You need either to send an excell file or prepare a web aplication.

Answer (score 0):

Once you (or your designer) have the completed design of the PDF, to make it interactive (with formulas), that is not to be done in InDesign. To make a form, see suggestion here:
[Creating an indesign fillable form with computation (addition)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64980/creating-an-indesign-fillable-form-with-computation-addition)